# Probability problem.

Tags: probability

We have two boxes, one (A) containing three red balls and two white balls, and another one (B) containing two red balls and two white balls.

We roll a dice, and if we get 1 or 2 we get one ball from box A (ball 1), put it in box B and get another ball from box B (ball 2); if we get a 3, 4, 5 or 6, we do the opposite: get ball 1 from box B, put it in box A and get ball 2 from box A.

What's the probability of ball 2 being white?

I have written every event that gives me a white ball in the second draw, and these are:

1. We get a 1 or 2, draw a white ball from box A, put it in B and draw a white ball from box B.
2. We get a 1 or 2, draw a red ball from box A, put it in B and draw a white ball from box B.
3. We get a 3, 4, 5 or 6, draw a white ball from box B, put it in A and draw a white ball from box B.
4. We get a 3, 4, 5 or 6, draw a red ball from box B, put it in A and draw a white ball from box B.

So the probability of the second ball being white, according to this reasoning is:

$\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{5}+\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{2}{5}+\frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{6}+\frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{6}=0.438$

I know that the answer is $0.287$ but I can't figure out what's wrong with my reasoning.

Comment: Why do you think the answer is $.287$?  That seems much too low.  It's $.4$ if you just draw from box A and .5 if you draw from box B, so why shod it come down so much?

Comment: In the worst case you add a red one to box A and then draw from A.  That would be a probability of $\frac 13$ so that's a lower bound

Comment: @lulu That is the answer in my probability notes made by my teacher.

Comment: Well, it seems to be wrong.

Comment: @lulu I get what you mean in the second comment. Is my way of reasoning the problem correct then?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your methodology,  and your answer fits the rough math I outlined,  so it makes sense, but I haven't checked the details....

Comment: Your arithmetic looks good too. Seems entirely correct.

Comment: I get the same answer as you. For a sense check, ball 2 is either a ball initially from box A or initially from box B. If it is a ball from Box A it has 0.4 chance of being white. If it is a ball from Box B it has a 0.5 chance of being white. So 0.4 is a lower bound on the ball being white (as balls within boxes are treated symmetrically). (Having said this, the question is not well written)